# Get data from push notification (FCM) without do click in notification

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, push, firebase-cloud-messaging

I already can manage push notifications from FCM when the app is in Foreground or background, when I do click in notification popup and open app "application didReceiveRemoteNotification" work without problem

My problem is that i don't know how get notification push data if the user open the app normaly (do click in icon app instead of click in notification) and I would lost the data if he close the notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app is in background state UINotification called **application didReceiveRemoteNotification** , If app is in open state UINotification called  **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**, And can't possible to get data without click on notification in iOS.

Comment: Then how whatsapp do in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

check

UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey
or
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions